# server will not reply (syn -ack)

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, kernel

I like to use the following commands to manage 'TIME_WAIT', in the hope to free up resources.

```
echo 20 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
```

I found something interesting while doing a tcpdump. Sometimes if a client makes a connection (syn), the server will not reply (syn -ack).

My question is, could it be because of the top three commands.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, yes: http://www.gadgetwiz.com/administration/kernel.html

I can't explain why, though.

Answer (score 1):

tw_recycle does not play well with load-balancers.

"Known to cause some issues with hoststated (load balancing and fail over) if enabled, should be used with caution."

http://www.speedguide.net/articles/linux-tweaking-121